# Connecting 2017 MBP with DisplayPort Cinema Display

Tags: macbook-pro, displayport, cinema-display

I have a MacBook Pro 2017 13" with High Sierra. Is it possible to somehow successfully connect a 27" Cinema Display with Mini DisplayPort to my MBP with an adapter?
I have read from some people that it worked and from some others that it didn't work.
Can you guys tell if it is possible? Because I have the opportunity to get a 27" Cinema Display for quite a cheap price (but only tomorrow because the person is there for a visit tomorrow).
Would be kinda sad if I would purchase a Monitor for 460 Euros just to find out, that these two devices are not compatible and probably never will be in the near future because there is and will not be a working adapter for this specific case..

Comment: That linked Question is *not* a duplicate. This Question is about an Apple monitor with a Mini DisplayPort, while that Question is about a different Apple display with a Dual Link DVI port.

Answer (score 0):

## Yes

The [current 2017 13" MacBook Pro page](https://www.apple.com/macbook-pro/) at Apple.com says it includes:

> Four Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) ports with support for:
>
> Charging
>
> DisplayPort
>
> Thunderbolt (up to 40 Gbps)
>
> USB 3.1 Gen 2 (up to 10 Gbps)

So you should be able to plug in a video cable to drive a Cinema Display that uses DisplayPort.

### Adapter: USB-C to Mini DisplayPort

The missing piece is a USB-C to Mini DisplayPort adapter. I do not see any for sale on Apple.com. I do see [several available at Amazon.com](https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/s/ref=is_s_ss_i_1_17?k=usb-c+mini+displayport+adapter&sprefix=usb-c+displayport&crid=NZ4RRX5R9YSP) costing around USD $ 20-40.

Be aware that you need a [Mini DisplayPort](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini_DisplayPort) not a [full-size DisplayPort](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort).